# For which values of $a$ does this system of equations $\mathbf{{not}}$ have a unique solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-rank

Here's my system of linear equations:

$\begin{cases}
x + 2y + 2z = 1\\x + ay + 3z = 3\\x + 11y +az = 0\\
\end{cases}$

Thus I have the augmented matrix $\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&2&2&1\\1&a&3&3\\1&11&a&0\end{array}\right]$

By row reduction, I obtain:

$\left[\begin{array}
{ccc|c}1&2&2&1\\0&a-2&1&2\\0&9&a-2&-1\end{array}\right]$

Unfortunately, I am stuck at this stage. I have tried swapping rows around but I didn't have much luck.

Update: I have managed to solve this with the use of the determinant.

Matrix of minors:
$\left[\begin{array}
{ccc}a^2-33&a-3&11-a\\2a-22&a-2&9\\6-2a&1&a-2\end{array}\right]$

Matrix of cofactors:
$\left[\begin{array}
{ccc}a^2-33&3-a&11-a\\22-a&9&a-2\\6-2a&-1&a-2\end{array}\right]$

Adjugate matrix:
$\left[\begin{array}
{ccc}a^2-33&22-2a&6-2a\\3-a&a-2&-1\\11-a&-9&a-2\end{array}\right]$

Det(A) = $1(a^2 - 33) + 2(3 - a) + 2(11 - a) = a^2 - 4a - 5$

$(a - 5)(a + 1) = 0$

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: so you want the matrix to have less than full rank, i.e., determinant equal to zero. that will give you either a consistent system with free variables, or an inconsistent system. Either way, there is no "unique solution" (either infinitely many, or nonte). And it should be easy to take the row reduction you did and figure out under what conditions you get zero determinant.

Comment: You may find it easier in this case to do row reduction to eliminate the last element in the last row (rather than the middle element). Equivalently, you're free to order your variables as $x,z,y$ and then the row reduction is slightly more trivial.

Comment: Thanks guys, I managed to solve it using row reduction and then again using the determinant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's rearrange the augmented matrix representing the system of linear equations, by swapping $R_2$ and $R_3$ (to avoid division by $a-2$ while row-reduction), to get

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&2&2&1\\1&11&a&0\\1&a&3&3\end{array}\right]$ and a subsequent row-reduction will give you

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&2&2&1\\0&9&a-2&-1\\0&0&1-\frac{(a-2)^2}{9}&2+\frac{a-2}{9}\end{array}\right]$

**Unique solution**:
in order for the system to have a unique solution, the coefficient and the augmented matrix both must be of full rank i.e., both must have rank $n=3$. To make that happen, we must have $1\neq\frac{(a-2)^2}{9} \implies a \notin \{-1,5\}$.

**No solution**:
for this to happen, we need to have the augment matrix rank higher than the coefficient matrix rank. This can happen if the coefficient matrix has rank < 3, e.g., if $1=\frac{(a-2)^2}{9} \implies a \in \{-1,5\}$ and augmented matrix has rank $n=3$ simultaneously, which means $2+\frac{a-2}{9} \neq 0 \implies a \neq -16$, i.e., for $a=-1,5$ the system will have no solution.

**Infinitely many solutions**:
it can happen iff both the coefficient and the augmented matrix are rank-deficient, i.e. for both of them the rank is $<3$. For this the last row of the augmented matrix needs to be zero. Which implies both $1-\frac{(a-2)^2}{9}=0 \implies a \in \{-1,5\}$ and $2+\frac{a-2}{9}=0 \implies a=-16$ simultaneously. Which is clearly impossible.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  Set the determinant equal to zero and solve for $a$.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is to use determinants: the system has a unique solution if and only if the matrix is invertible, i.e., if and only if the matrix has determinant *not* equal to $0$. So you can compute the determinant (either in your original or row-reduced matrix) in terms of $a$, set it equal to $0$, and solve for $a$. But if you do not know this yet, you can proceed as follows:

If $a=2$, then the system clearly has a unique solution, so you may assume $a\neq 2$. The reason to do this is so that we can continue the row reduction by multiplying by $a-2$. Multiply the second row by $9$ and the last row by $a-2$ to get:
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 2 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 9(a-2) & 9 & 18\\
0 & 9(a-2) & (a-2)^2 & 2-a
\end{array}\right).$$
Subtracting the second row from the third row, we get
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 2 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 9(a-2) & 9 & 18\\
0 & 0 & (a-2)^2-9 & -16-a
\end{array}\right).$$
So: you will have a unique solution if $(a-2)^2-9\neq 0$. If $(a-2)^2-9=0$, you either get infinitely many solutions (if $16+a=0$ as well), or no solutions (if $-16-a\neq 0$). So now we just need to figure out when that bottom right entry of the coefficient matrix is $0$.

Comment: Thank you, Arturo. Does subtracting 18 from (2 - a) not equal (-16 - a)?

Comment: @ZoeB: I may have done it backwards in my head... you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Well if $a = 2$ you have $z=2; y=-\frac 19$ and $x = whatever$.

But if $a-2\ne 0$ keep at it.

Multiply row 2 by $\frac 9{a-2}$ and subtract getting rows.

$\begin{array}\\
1&2&2&|\,\,1\\
0&a-2&1&|\,\,2\\
0&0&(a-2)-\frac 9{a-2}&|-\frac 9{a-2}\\
\end{array}$

Now if $(a-2)-\frac 9{a-2} = 0$ we have a case with not solutions.

That is if $(a-2)^2 = 9$ of $a = 5,-1$.

If we assume $a\ne 2,5,-1$ then we can reduce

$\begin{array}\\
1&2&2&|\,\,1\\
0&1&\frac 1{a-2}&|\,\,\frac 2{a-2}\\
0&0&1&|-\frac 9{a-2}\cdot\frac 1{(a-2)-\frac 9{a-2}}=-\frac{9}{(a-2)^2-9}\\
\end{array}$

..... and that's in the whatchamacallit form "upper triangle"?) so we know this results in a unique solution.

So $a = 5$ or $1$ are the cases without solutions.

(because we'd get $((a-2)-\frac 9{a-2})z=-\frac 9{a-2}$ which if $a = 5$ is

$(3-3)z = -3$ or $0 = 3$ and if $a=-1$ we get $(-3 + 3)z = 3$ or $0 = 3$.